# How to properly insert the values from my output to a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
Text = '''Game of Thrones is an American fantasy drama television series created by David Benioff and D. B. Weiss for HBO. The show was both produced and filmed in Belfast elsewhere in the United Kingdom.'''

import re
new_text = ''
punctuations = '''!.,'''
for character in Text:
    if character not in punctuations:
        new_text = new_text + character
from collections import Counter
split_text = Text.split(' ')
count = Counter(split_text)
most_freq_word_new = [key for key,valu in count.items() if valu == max(count.values())]

result =  {i: [] for i in most_freq_word_new}     #Create Dict with word as key and list as value
for index, word in enumerate(split_text):
    for i in most_freq_word_new:
        if word == i:
            #print (word)
            suffix_word =  split_text[index + 1]
            #print (suffix_word)
            prefix_word =  split_text[index - 1]
            #print (prefix_word)
            result[word].extend([suffix_word, prefix_word])  #Use list.extend to add to result.
            #print (result[word])
print(result)
```

My current output is below:

```
{'and': ['D.', 'Benioff', 'filmed', 'produced'], 'in': ['Belfast', 'filmed', 'the', 'elsewhere']}
```

My desired output is below:

```
{'and': 
     {suffix_word:['D.', 'filmed'], 
     prefix_word: ['Benioff', 'produced']}
'in': 
    {suffix_word:['Belfast', 'the'], 
    prefix_word: ['filmed','elsewhere']}}
```

Comment: Are you sure your expected output is correct?

Comment: :) edited the exepected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. Just need to slightly change your code to achieve that:

```py
import re
from collections import Counter

Text = '''Game of Thrones is an American fantasy drama television series created by David Benioff and D. B. Weiss for HBO. The show was both produced and filmed in Belfast elsewhere in the United Kingdom.'''

split_text = Text.split(' ')
count = Counter(split_text)
most_freq_word_new = [key for key,valu in count.items() if valu == max(count.values())]

result =  {i: {"suffix_word": [], "prefix_word": []} for i in most_freq_word_new}     #Create Dict with word as key and list as value
for index, word in enumerate(split_text):
    for i in most_freq_word_new:
        if word == i:
            suffix_word =  split_text[index + 1] if index < len(split_text)-1 else ""
            prefix_word =  split_text[index - 1] if index > 0 else ""
            result[word]["suffix_word"].append(suffix_word)
            result[word]["prefix_word"].append(prefix_word)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
{'and': {'suffix_word': ['D.', 'filmed'], 'prefix_word': ['Benioff', 'produced']}, 'in': {'suffix_word': ['Belfast', 'the'], 'prefix_word': ['filmed', 'elsewhere']}}
```

Comment: What is mean bt. if index < len(split_text) else ""

Comment: if `index` is 9 and `len(split_text)` is 10, then `split_text[index + 1]` will try to get the index after the last one, which doesn't exist since it's the last word. The check after that `if index < len(split_text)-1 else ""` makes sure to put an empty string as the next word since it doesn't exist. (Thanks for asking actually, I fixed a small mistake)

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex for this purpose. I used  [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) for this

```
import re
from collections import Counter
Text = '''Game of Thrones is an American fantasy drama television series created by David Benioff and D. B. Weiss for HBO. The show was both produced and filmed in Belfast elsewhere in the United Kingdom.'''
count=Counter(Text.split())
most_freq_word_new = [key for key,valu in count.items() if valu == max(count.values())]
result =  {i: {"suffix_word": [], "prefix_word": []} for i in most_freq_word_new}  
for word in most_freq_word_new:
    for prefix,suffix in re.findall(r'([\w.]+) '+ word + r' ([\w.]+)',Text):
        result[word]['prefix_word'] .append( prefix)
        result[word]['suffix_word'] .append( suffix)
print(result)
```

OUTPUT

```
{'and': {'prefix_word': ['Benioff', 'produced'], 'suffix_word': ['D.', 'filmed']}, 'in': {'prefix_word': ['filmed', 'elsewhere'], 'suffix_word': ['Belfast', 'the']}}
```

Comment: The OP's code depends on `most_freq_word_new` so your solution wouldn't quite work.

Comment: @Akaisteph7 Modified to make it work which I think the OP would want

Comment: @Akaisteph7 its actually really hard to tell what to OP wants :P, if `and` is the first word in `Text` followed by the rest of text then your code and mine produces to different outputs. And I dont know which is the one the OP would prefer.

Comment: You have my upvote. And of the second comment, that is a good point.. Mine is definitely not right.. will change that.

Comment: Just noticed that it's also an issue if there is a dot right after the word.. xD